# Unital Ring Homomorphisms Questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

In my class we define a ring to always have identity element. So then we define a Ring Homomorphisms as follows,

Let $f:R \to S$ be a mapping. Then $f$ is a ring homomorphism if

$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$ 
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$$

$$f(1_R)=1_S$$

I am asked to find all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{}Z_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_{15}$.

My question is, wouldn't there be no Ring Homomorphisms using the definition of a Ring homomorphism that I have?

This is because, let $f$ be some homomorphism satisfying the conditions above then,

$$0=f(0)=f(6)=6f(1)=6$$

which is a contradiciton since $f(0)=0$.

I'm aware of the other definition of a ring homomorphism when a ring isn't defined to always have an identity in which the last condition is relaxed.

Doesn't the definition that I use imply that there will never be a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ whenever $m \neq n$?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean $f(1_{R}) = 1_{S}$?

Comment: You are correct, there is no ring homom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a ring homomorphism $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ if and only if $n\mid  m$, since we must have $m \cdot 1\bmod m\implies m\cdot1\bmod n=0$, in other words $n\equiv 0\mod n$.